# Relativistic doppler effect vs cosmological redshift

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

If these two would interfere what would happen?
consider two bodies away from each other at certain distance which one is source of a light ray and other is receiver. and they have relative speed of v towards each other which is designated to cause the same blueshift in light ray from doppler effect that the expansion is causing in that distance as redshift. now when the receiver observes the light is it redshifted? or nothing happens?
(English is not my first language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift is a single number, and it can cancel. So if something is moving to us at exactly the right speed to cancel the cosmological redshift, it will appear to have redshift $z = 0$. For similar reasons we see some galaxies in the Virgo cluster to have blueshifts, even though the universe is expanding.

See [this article](http://www.astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2017/12/blueshifted-galaxies) for more.

> When we measure the redshift or blueshift of light from distant galaxies, it is the sum of the cosmological redshift and the Doppler shift (either red or blue) from their peculiar motion relative to us. In the nearby universe, light travel times and cosmological redshifts are relatively small, so sometimes the peculiar motion “wins” and we observe some galaxies with blueshifts. Something like 100 nearby galaxies have blueshifts. Most of these are Local Group dwarf galaxies; however, the Andromeda Galaxy (M31) has a blueshift of about 186 miles per second (300 km/s). It is heading toward us and will merge with the Milky Way in about 4 billion years. We also see some of the galaxies in the Virgo Cluster with blueshifts (e.g., M86 and the dwarf galaxies near it) as they move at large velocities relative to the center of the Virgo Cluster.